# I want to store results from a loop into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am a total noob at Ruby so I am learning from people who know :)
I do have looked for this answer but in vain...

I'd like to get the result from my loop into a new array. But I can't...

```
@angelco_account = ["https://angel.co/unstock", "https://angel.co/groupclip"]

@angelco_account.each do |i|
  @twitter_url = []
  @twitter_url << Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{i}", "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.001(windows; U; NT4.0; en-us)  Gecko/25250101")).css('a.twitter_url.icon_link.fontello-twitter')[0]["href"]
  puts @twitter_url
end
```

I got this result in my irb

```
 https://twitter.com/UnStock_Market
 https://twitter.com/groupclip
 => ["https://angel.co/unstock", "https://angel.co/groupclip"]
```

I want to have that for puts `@twitter_url`

```
["https://twitter.com/UnStock_Market", "https://twitter.com/groupclip"]
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are assigning `@twitter_url` to empty array on *each iteration*. Generally speaking, swapping lines:

```
@angelco_account.each do |i|
  @twitter_url = []
```

to:

```
@twitter_url = []
@angelco_account.each do |i|
```

should do the trick. But for this purpose it’s better to use [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
@twitter_url = @angelco_account.each_with_object([]) do |i, memo|
  memo << Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{i}", ...).
            css('a.twitter_url.icon_link.fontello-twitter')[0]["href"]
end
puts @twitter_url
```

or, in this particular case, [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) will suffice:

```
@twitter_url = @angelco_account.map do |account|
  Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{i}", ...).
    css('a.twitter_url.icon_link.fontello-twitter')[0]["href"]
end
puts @twitter_url
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna try this !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use idiomatic Ruby you can do this:

```
@angelco_account = ["https://angel.co/unstock", "https://angel.co/groupclip"]
@twitter_url = @angelco_account.map {|url| Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{url}", "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.001(windows; U; NT4.0; en-us)  Gecko/25250101")).css('a.twitter_url.icon_link.fontello-twitter')[0]["href"] }
puts @twitter_url
```